# pyinstaller to creating wrong 1 _MEIxxxx folder, but trying to open another

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

If this is happening to you, the error (In this case) is a broken installation of pyinstaller or python, remove it from the computer and do a fresh reinstallation.

When trying to create a exe with pyinstaller, it works fine and the bundled .dll file is included an it unpacks the _MEI folder with the necesarry files the correct places. BUT i creates one called _MEIxxx but tries to open a _MEIxxY which does not exist (yes, both changes name everytime it is launched)

I cannot see anywhere you can manually set the name of the _MEI folder which would make it much easier.

The cmd command i am running is:

```
pyinstaller script.py --add-data "PATH TO DLL\python39.dll;test" -F --runtime-tmpdir .
```

reproducible problem:

creating a fresh .py project with python 3.9(i use pycharm)
include code of:

```
print("HI")
```

then in cmd use:

```
pyinstaller main.py -F (we want it to be a onefile exe)
```

Then the .exe file is copied to another pc
Here we run it with CMD to see the error output.

It returns the error:

```
Error loading Python DLL: "path to local\Temp\_MEIXXXX\python39.dll
```

Comment: @Alexander the minimal example:

Create a new python file, does not need code in it to reproduce the error. 
use pyinstaller to create a .exe file `pyinstaller main.py --add-data "PATH TO DLL\python39.dll;asset" -F --runtime-tmpdir .` Since the .dll file is needed to run on another computer which might not have the same python version.

Comment: When opened on the other computer with cmd, the error:

**Error loading Python DLL 'C:\Users\Frederik\Desktop\new\_MEI181682\python39.dll'.
LoadLibrary: The named module could not be found.**

Sometimes it creates the _MEI folder without deleting it, in the folder the .dll file can be found.

Comment: yeah thought so, did it to make sure it was included with the right name and everything.

i don't? i can see it looks after it self, i thought it did it to be able to run/compile the .exe file since the computer does not have the same python version installed.

Comment: when creating a .exe with pyinstaller and moving the .exe file to another computer, it cannot be run due to it needing a python39.dll (or for whatever version python it was made with) the script itself can have zero code, or as much code in it without changing the error.

Therefore it is being compiled with the python.dll file, but when launching it on a new pc, the dll file cannot be found

Comment: if i don't, i get the same error of it not being able to find the pyhton39.dll

Comment: i did include it earlier, it is now also edited into the question itself, the code is not important as the error is the same with zero code, or with one line of code printing hi

Comment: If that is really all it is then there is something funny up with your pyinstaller instillation or your python installation.... Try uninstalling both and starting fresh.  Try it out on a virtual machine first if you want to be extra cautious i suppose

Comment: okay, thought it was something with pyinstaller not being able to point to the .dll correcly. trying it now, thank you so far

Comment: it was exclusively windows so the ";" should work.

I found the error, you were right... it was simply a broken pyinstaller or python. editing the question now to include it and creating an answer. thank you so much for your help. seriusly, i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error (In this case) is a broken installation of pyinstaller or python, remove it from the computer and do a fresh reinstallation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).